# Group Joining Method Throwing Exception in SignalR

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, .net, signalr

we have created a live chat application in IOS where back-end is in c# .net and for live communication SignalR is Used

**PROBLEM:- not able to call method in c# SignalR from ios application,it works fine for the first time the chat is also works but after disconnecting and when going for second round the signalr is not able to call the method i have put some logs and i got the below exception details**

> 2019-04-11 09:03:26,918 ERROR MonitoringLogger
>
> > Exception ---System.InvalidOperationException: 'addToGroup' method could not be resolved. Potential candidates are: 
> >     addToGroup(un:String, ui:String, gn:String, dt:String):Void
>
> at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.NullMethodDescriptor.b__6_0(IHub emptyHub, Object[] emptyParameters)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.Incoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext context)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubPipelineModule.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

c# Code
Server Side Method

```
public void addToGroup(string un, string ui, string gn, string dt )
{
   // business logic
}
```

IOS Code
Client Side Code

```
[chat invoke:@"addToGroup" withArgs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:userName,userId,groupName, deviceId, nil] completionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Resposne:%@",response);
completion(response,error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is from connection id
signalR provides conenctinId on every single connection
once you closed connection then next time the conenctionid is different not same as last one.
i am c# developer so i thing, this creating issue, let me know with hub information so i can provide you exact solution.

Comment: Hi jimmy darji thanks for your response I understand the concept of connection in which you mention above but if the connection id is different as I know then there should be no problem to establish new connection right? but still, I'm facing the issue